Remove Whitespace in PowerShell Scriptblock
I'm writing some script blocks to a text file like so:
$scriptblock = ""

if (1 -eq 1) {
    if (2 -eq 2) {    
        $scriptblock = {
            try {
                $test = "This string contains spaces";
            } catch {
                $test = "So does this";
            }
        }
    }
}                                    
                                                
$scriptblock | out-file c:\temp\scriptblock.txt  

But when i write it to the text file, I end up with all the white space before each line.  So it looks like this:
            try {
                $test = "This string contains spaces";
            } catch {
                $test = "So does this";
            }

instead of this:
try {
    $test = "This string contains spaces";
} catch {
    $test = "So does this";
}

If i don't indent my original code, it will probably work.  But then I lose my indentations.  Is there any way to do this from a coding perspective?  Thanks.

UPDATE 2:
Modified the answer with the specific needs of OP, getting the basic indent value from the last item instead of the first. But only because he asked politely!
UPDATE:
I WARMLY suggest using the module I linked in the original answer at the bottom for this.
But if it's impossible, have a very quick, very dirty function
function Format-ScriptBlock {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [scriptblock]$Script
    )
    
    
    process {
        # turns scriptblock in string array, removing all empty or whitespace-only lines
        $ScriptArray = $Script.ToString().Split("`n", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries).Where({ -not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) })

        # gets the base-indent of the first line
        # $BaseIndent = $ScriptArray[0].Length - $ScriptArray[0].TrimStart().Length

        # As alternative: get the base-indent from the last line
        $BaseIndent = $ScriptArray[$ScriptArray.count-1].Length - $ScriptArray[$ScriptArray.count-1].TrimStart().Length

        
        # remove the same amount of spaces from all the line
        $ScriptArray -replace "^\s{$BaseIndent}", ''
    }
    
}

Format-ScriptBlock $scriptblock | Out-File '.\scriptblock.txt'

ORIGINAL:
Use Invoke-Formatter from the module PSScriptAnalyzer
$scriptblock |Invoke-Formatter | Out-File '.\scriptblock.txt'


I didn't want to rely on "external" modules, but this is nice to know....thanks.

added a dirty alternative

I think $array should be $ScriptArray.  But i'll give it a test!  Thanks!

yeah, my bad. Fixed, thank you. Hope it works for you

Can you modify your code to be: $BaseIndent = $ScriptArray[$ScriptArray.count-1].Length - $ScriptArray[$ScriptArray.count-1].TrimStart().Length
I found that if my scriptblock starts on the same line, like this:
$scriptblock = { try {
It will be subsequent lines that are incorrectly indented.  So I've got the indent from the last line instead....

I'm unsure why should change the code given you already fixed it for yourself. I DID write it was a very dirty function

So i can mark it as an answer! ;-)
